# Token validation ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, .net-6.0

I'm trying to secure APIs using a token. In broad terms, my idea is as follows:

I want to use an Identity and Access Management (IAM) system to generate the authentication token, and with this token, it should be possible to access my APIs.

To test everything, I've registered an application on Azure. I've added the following code in the `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
            (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
              builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]
                )),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
        };
    });
```

Since I'm not entirely sure I've understood how to replace the values correctly, I'll try to write down what I've done here:

- Jwt:Issuer -> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant) id}
- Jwt:Audience -> "https://{domain}.azurewebsites.net"
- Jwt:Key -> I wasn't entirely sure what to put here, so I used the client secret of the registered app.

The issue is that whenever I try to generate the token, I always receive an "Unauthorized" response.

Could someone help me or guide me better in resolving this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: how are you generating the token?

Comment: Hello dareredevil, i'm generating the code calling the api Microsoft login.microsoft.com/Tennantid/token